Task: I want to insert TAX column value and update the HIGHEST column value as per condition which is mention in code
CREATE TABLE RSUOM 
(
    EMPID NUMBER,
    EMPNAME VARCHAR2(50), 
    SALARY NUMBER, 
    TAX NUMBER, 
    PERCENT_TAX NUMBER, 
    HIGHEST VARCHAR2(3)
);

INSERT INTO RSUOMS (EMPID, EMPNAME, SALARY, PERCENT_TAX) 
VALUES (11, 'RAM', 10000, 10);
INSERT INTO RSUOMS (EMPID, EMPNAME, SALARY, PERCENT_TAX) 
VALUES (12, 'RAMA', 20000, 10);

SELECT * FROM RSUOMS ;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER RSUOM1_TRIGGER
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON RSUOM1
    DECLARE
        MAX_TAX NUMBER;
BEGIN
    UPDATE RSUOM1 
    SET TAX = SALARY * PERCENT_TAX / 100;

    SELECT MAX(TAX) INTO MAX_TAX FROM RSUOM1;

    UPDATE RSUOM1 
    SET HIGHEST = CASE 
                      WHEN TAX = MAX_TAX THEN 'YES'
                      ELSE 'NO'
                  END;
END;
/

I get this error:

ORA-00036: MAXIMUM NUMBER OF RECURSIVE SQL LEVELS (50) EXCEEDED
ORA-04088: ERROR DURING EXECUTION OF TRIGGER
INSERT INTO RSUOMS (EMPID, EMPNAME, SALARY) VALUES (13,'ANKIT',30000);

CAN ANYONE TELL ME WHERE IS THE MISTAKE OR HOW I CAN RESOLVE THE ERROR?

You are creating recursive code with no end. There is an after insert or update trigger on table RSUOM1. That trigger executes an update statement on RSUOM1... that update statement fires the trigger again. After 50 times it bails out...

Even if this would work...there are also no where clauses in any of the update statements. So each update statement updates all rows in the table.

The create statement is for a table "RSUOM". The insert statements are for table "RSUOMS" and the trigger is on "RSUOM1". Is that all supposed to be the same table ?

yes, RSUOM and RSUOM1 are same table. Please let me know how can solve this query

This can be achieved using a compound trigger. In the after statement section, check if an update is needed and only run the update statement if there is a mismatch. When this logic is included the trigger recursion is removed and the insert runs fine.
create or replace TRIGGER rsuom_trigger
FOR INSERT OR UPDATE ON rsuom
COMPOUND TRIGGER
    BEFORE EACH ROW IS
    BEGIN
        -- set column value with bind variable syntax. No UPDATE
        :NEW.tax :=  :NEW.salary * :NEW.percent_tax / 100;
    END BEFORE EACH ROW;

    AFTER STATEMENT IS
        l_max_tax rsuom.tax%TYPE;
        l_highest_update_needed NUMBER;
        l_not_highest_update_needed NUMBER;
    BEGIN
        SELECT MAX(tax) INTO l_max_tax FROM RSUOM;
        -- check if an update is needed for the max tax
        BEGIN
            SELECT 1 INTO l_highest_update_needed FROM DUAL WHERE EXISTS
              (SELECT 1 FROM RSUOM WHERE tax = l_max_tax AND NVL(highest,'X') != 'YES' );
        EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
            l_highest_update_needed := 0;
        END;
        -- check if an update is needed for records that are not max tax
        BEGIN
            SELECT 1 INTO l_not_highest_update_needed FROM DUAL WHERE EXISTS
              (SELECT 1 FROM rsuom WHERE tax != l_max_tax AND NVL(highest,'X') != 'NO' );
        EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
            l_not_highest_update_needed := 0;
        END;
        IF l_highest_update_needed = 1 THEN
            UPDATE rsuom
                SET highest = 'YES' WHERE tax = l_max_tax;
        END IF;
        IF l_not_highest_update_needed = 1 THEN
            UPDATE rsuom
                SET highest = 'NO' WHERE tax != l_max_tax;
        END IF;
    END AFTER STATEMENT;
    
END rsuom_trigger;
/

Trigger RSUOM_TRIGGER compiled

19c>INSERT INTO RSUOM (EMPID, EMPNAME, SALARY,PERCENT_TAX  ) VALUES (11,'RAM', 100, 10);

1 row inserted.

19c>INSERT INTO RSUOM (EMPID, EMPNAME, SALARY, PERCENT_TAX ) VALUES (12,'RAMA',300, 10);

1 row inserted.

19c>INSERT INTO RSUOM (EMPID, EMPNAME, SALARY, PERCENT_TAX ) VALUES (14,'KOEN',100, 10);

1 row inserted.

19c>INSERT INTO RSUOM (EMPID, EMPNAME, SALARY, PERCENT_TAX ) VALUES (14,'STEVEN',400, 10);

1 row inserted.

19c>select * from rsuom;

   EMPID EMPNAME       SALARY    TAX    PERCENT_TAX HIGHEST    
________ __________ _________ ______ ______________ __________ 
      11 RAM              100     10             10 NO         
      12 RAMA             300     30             10 NO         
      14 KOEN             100     10             10 NO         
      14 STEVEN           400     40             10 YES        

19c>

For future posts... please clean up your own code and DON'T SHOUT (google "is it ok to write in all caps" to find out why).

Can we write above statement using compound trigger and collection? Please help me in this

I don't know from the top of my head. I'd say this question is answered. You asked a question and the solution I posted does the job. I suggest you have a go at it this other method you want. Research and try, don't give up rightaway. There are many resources. If you get stuck then post a new question. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, it is a place for developers to ask for help when they're stuck.
